# Hive:No space available in any of the local directories

Tags: hive

I am running HQL queries, and a query failed. hive.log said shows below information

```
Task with the most failures(4):

Task ID:

  task_1405329224037_10272_m_000006

Diagnostic Messages for this Task: 

**No space available in any of the local directories**.
```

What does the last sentence mean? It's very strange that I can't event get a full match while googling using the last sentence. Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

It meant that the datanode( job run ) or the namenode disk space might be full. Freeing the space would solve the issue.